# How to use re.sub in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-group, regex-greedy

```
Text = "<a> text </a> <c> code </c>"
```

I want to remove `<c> code </c>`  statement in python

```
output = "<a> text </a>"
```

Comment: Use something like `re.sub(r'<c>.*?</c>', '', Text)`.

Comment: Perhaps relevant (and definitely entertaining): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454  Are you sure regex are the right tool to solve your issue?

Comment: so thanks, worked properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "<a> text </a> <c> code </c>"
>>> new_text = re.sub(r'<c>.*?</c>', '', text)
>>> new_text
<a> text </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we can simply add both opening and closing tags and everything in between in a capturing group:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(<a>.+<\/a>)"

test_str = "<a> text </a> <c> code </c>"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pgfr1O/1/)

```js
const regex = /(<a>.+<\/a>).+/gm;
const str = `<a> text </a> <c> code </c>`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: They just want to remove it, not do... all of this ^

Comment: The premise behind this is incorrect. What if OP actually has some tag `<b> ... </b>` that they implicitly want to keep? They've stated that want to remove `<c> ... </c>`, leaving everything else unchanged. Your tacit assumption that there are only two types of tags isn't a reasonable one.

Answer (score 1):

```
 import re
 text = "<a> text </a> <c> code </c>"
 rg = r"<c>.*<\/c>"
 for match in re.findall(rg, text):
     text = text.replace(match, "")
```